# Viewing contents of hive directly through data files

Tags: hadoop, hive

So, the problem is that for really large tables, hive takes a ridiculous amount of time to just show you some rows of the table. So for example,

```
select * from table limit 1000;
```

might take 20 minutes for a billion record table. I thought it might be a lot faster to just peek at the data files hive stores for the tables. I can do that using -

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://ipAddr/mnt/hive/<path to one of the table files> | head
```

The problem is that the lines appear as one big line with no apparent delimiters. It is thus very difficult to tell when one column ends and another one begins. Now, there must be a delimiter in these files that separates the columns, just that cat is not able to see it for some reason. Is there a way to peek into the data rows with some kind of visible delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Hive uses ctrl-A as the delimiter (character 1), so i suggest you replace it with tab, or comma, or whatever:

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://ipAddr/mnt/hive/<path>  | tr '\001' '\t' | head
```